# Infinite loop in android background service, battery drain issues?

Tags: android, performance, service, infinite-loop

I'm writing an app that, among other things, will notify via notification pepople who everyday commute, if the public transport they usually take have some kind of delay.

I considered implement this function using the AlarmManager, but I found too many problems related to how many public transport are chosen and what days the user decides to receive the notifications.

So I came up with another solution: save the user preference into a file, and launch a background service that checks that file every 5 minutes, and if the conditions are respected, it shows the notification:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    while(true){
        try{              
            if (fileCheck()){
                Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.avanti).setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)).setSound(alarmSound);
                mBuilder.setContentText("Test");
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
                Thread.sleep(300000)
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored){}
    }
}
```

And it works, but I have a doubt: is this going to cause performance or battery drain issues? Or is it safe since it sleeps most of the time?

Comment: Your first problem is that it will crash, with the background equivalent of an ANR. You are trying to sleep for 5 minutes on the main application thread, which will not work. Your second problem is that your process will eventually be terminated, and you will no longer be getting control every 5 minutes anyway.

Comment: @CommonsWare so do you think I shouls try moving it to an IntentService, or find a way to solve my problem and use AlarmManager?

Comment: The best answer is to move most of your code to a server and use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) if and when a condition is met that the user needs to know about. The next-best answer is to use `JobScheduler`, if your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher. The next-next-best answer is to use `AlarmManager`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll settle for the next-next-best answer, thanks for your help!